# Webelement identification in Xpath

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am working on `xpath` and I have a query regarding this. Below is the relevant html code for the getting input to a text box:

```
<div id="formId:fld_SHIPPING_ADDRESS__PHONE_PRIMARY_id_wrapper" 
     class="fld_SHIPPING_ADDRESS__PHONE_PRIMARY_id ">
  <label id="formId:lbl_SHIPPING_ADDRESS__PHONE_PRIMARY_id" style="" 
         for="formId:fld_SHIPPING_ADDRESS__PHONE_PRIMARY_id">
  **<input id="formId:fld_SHIPPING_ADDRESS__PHONE_PRIMARY_id" type="text" maxlength="20" 
           value="" name="formId:fld_SHIPPING_ADDRESS__PHONE_PRIMARY_id"/>**
  <span id="formId:fld_SHIPPING_ADDRESS__PHONE_PRIMARY_id_msg"/>
</div>
```

I wrote the Xpath as

```
 driver.findElement(
     By.xpath("//input[@id = 'formId:fld_SHIPPING_ADDRESS__PHONE_PRIMARY_id')]"))
.sendKeys("test");
```

This is the only matching node in the html and when I run it I'm getting the below error

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id = 'formId:fld_SHIPPING_ADDRESS__PHONE_PRIMARY_id']"}
>   Command duration or timeout: 104.80 seconds
>   For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Kindly help for the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked your source code and found that your input box is contained within a frame.

Use the following code :-

```
//switch to the frame
driver.switchTo().frame("envoy");   

//get the phone number field and enter data 
driver.findElement(By.id("formId:fld_SHIPPING_ADDRESS__PHONE_PRIMARY_id")).sendKeys("");
```

In the above code I have used id as locator. I'd recommend that you use name or id over xpath. Your web application under test is beautifully coded with proper id and name tags!!

Let me know if this is useful for you.

Comment: switchTo().frame("envoy"); worked for me.Thanks a lot for the valuable inputs

Answer (score 0):

**You can start by fixing the following issues in your code:**

1. Close the `<label>` tag with a corresponding `</label>` tag.
2. Remove the two spaces in the `@id =` string.

If the above solves the `NoSuchElementException` that you're getting, then you will probably also need to extend `.sendKeys("test")` into `.sendKeys("test").submit()`, in order to complete this issue.

Comment: I did the required changes and even then also I am getting the same error message after the run

Comment: Can you post the URL of the web-page that you are trying to automate?

Comment: https://www.overstock.com/ - once u click the 'checkout' u will be redirected to the checkout page where I am trying to input the value to "Primary phone number"

Comment: There is no such option `checkout`.